# import csv into R with missing values as "N

Tags: r, csv, import, read.csv

I have a csv data file to be imported into R, but I got problem for one column.

```
data <- read.csv("example.csv", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ";", colClasses = c("character","character", rep("character", 2),"numeric",rep("character",6),rep("numeric",5)))

Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '"N'
```

I realize it is because one column contains missing values and is listed as "N. For example, one problematic data line is like:

```
11e9-afea;"N;"Passenger Car";"SEDAN";"2019";"BMW";"M5";"Gas";"All Wheel Drive";"Automatic";"";"18.1512";"29.0277";"15";"17";"21"
```

Supposedly, the data line like below has no problem to be read:

```
11e9-afea;"4";"Passenger Car";"SEDAN";"2019";"BMW";"M5";"Gas";"All Wheel Drive";"Automatic";"";"18.1512";"29.0277";"15";"17";"21"
```

How can I deal with all the "N and import the data correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: try with `na.strings = "N")` i.e. `data <- read.csv("example.csv", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ";", colClasses = c("character","character", rep("character", 2),"numeric",rep("character",6),rep("numeric",5)), na.strings = c('"N', ""))`

Comment: How was this file created? The "N" with unbalanced quotes is going to be very troublesome. That's just not a valid CSV file. I might try to fix the problem upstream.

Comment: @akrun Thanks but I tried your suggestion by setting na.strings as "N before. Not working as well.